# File::Temp pass system command output to temp file

Tags: perl

I'm trying to capture the output of a *tail command* to a temp file.

here is a sample of my [apache access log](http://pastebin.com/raw/TXDgaT2E)

Here is what I have tried so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Temp ();
use File::Temp qw/ :seekable /;

chomp($tail = `tail access.log`);

my $tmp = File::Temp->new( UNLINK => 0, SUFFIX => '.dat' );
print $tmp "Some data\n";
print "Filename is $tmp\n";
```

I'm not sure how I can go about passing the output of `$tail` to this temporoy file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would use a different approach for tailing the file. Have a look to [File::Tail](http://search.cpan.org/~mgrabnar/File-Tail-1.3/Tail.pm), I think it will simplify things.

Comment: It's generally bad practice to use a shell command when you can write the equivalent natively in Perl. But I'm okay with it in this instance as there is only one such command, and `File::Tail` isn't a core module so it may well need to be installed

Comment: I agree, but I (wrongly) assumed that he actually wanted to `tail -f` the file in a continuous way. My mistake, I always tend to assume a continuous tail...

Comment: Ah, then I would agree with you. To do that with the shell command would involve opening a pipe from `tail`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like all you need is

```
print $tmp $tail;
```

But you also need to *declare* `$tail` and you probably shouldn't `chomp` it, so

```
my $tail = `tail access.log`;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is many ways to do this but since you are happy to use modules, you might as well use [File::Tail](http://search.cpan.org/~mgrabnar/File-Tail-1.3/Tail.pm);

```
use v5.12;
use warnings 'all';
use File::Tail;

my $lines_required = 10;
my $out_file = "output.txt";

open(my $out, '>', $out_file) or die "$out_file: $!\n";
my $tail = File::Tail->new("/some/log/file");
for (1 .. $lines_required)  {
    print $out $tail->read;
}
close $out;
```

This sits and monitors the log file until it gets the 10 new lines.  If you just want a copy of the last 10 lines as is, the easiest way is to use I/O redirection from the shell: `tail /some/log/file > my_copy.txt`

Comment: It would help us to pass on the message that `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` were *mandatory* if you were to use them in your solution code. There's little point in using `my` without `use strict`

Comment: Oh yes - I normally at least have "use v5.12" which is strict by default.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: As it stands you are using `File::Tail` in its *monitoring* mode. It will block waiting for new data to be written to the file and the `while` loop will never exit. a call to `tail` will just print the last ten lines and exit

Answer (score 0):

Is classic Perl approach to use the proper filename for the handle?

```
if(open LOGFILE, 'tail /some/log/file |' and open TAIL, '>/tmp/logtail')
{
    print LOGFILE "$_\n" while <TAIL>;
    close TAIL and close LOGFILE
}
```